# Trying to remove multiples of the same number in Python

Tags: python, list, class

I'm trying to remove numbers from a list that are the same. So if I have 1,2,3,4,5,3 and I tell it to remove 3, it will only remove the first one (using .remove) to give me 1,2,4,5,3. I now know that .remove is only supposed to remove the first one, so my question is, what other method can I use? I've tried .pop and del but neither seem to do all of them (though I could have been doing it wrong). I would have just made a new list without the repeating number but it's meant to go through my teachers driver so I can't just make up a new list (or at least, I'm assuming there's any easier way?) In case it helps, here's that part of the code so far:

```
    def remove_element(self,integer):
        self.integer = integer
        self.members.remove(integer)
```

Comment: Are you sure your data structure should be a list instead of a set? What do you actually need to do with it?

Comment: According to my teacher, that's what she wants. Our class is called Set but then we are using a list to do everything

Comment: So I decided to ignore what she told us and made it into a set anyways, bc you're right, a set made way more sense. Idk why she told us to build a list, something to ask about in class next time ><

Comment: I think it's supposed to be making you think about implementation details - though if that's the idea, something a bit lower-level than Python might be better. If the class is any good, one of the next few assignments will have you reimplement this with a hash table you'll write yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the built-in `filter`, and you don't have to write a method for it:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3]
>>> filter(lambda f: f != 3, l)
[1, 2, 4, 5]
```

In the code above, we define a lambda function `lambda f: f != 3`, which test if an element in the list is 3 or not.  In your case, you might use `self.integer` to replace `3`.

If you are not familiar with lambda function, `lambda f: f != 3` is equivalent to the function `foo`:

```
>>> def foo(f):
...     return f != 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5,3]
>>> 
>>> [i for i in l if i != 3]
[1, 2, 4, 5]
```

Just remember that this doesn't actually modify `l` but instead creates a *new* list, so be sure to reassign `l` to the result of the comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

[list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), e.g:

```
[x for x in a_list if x != integer]
```

So in your case it would be:

```
def remove_element(self,integer):
    self.integer = integer
    self.members = [elem for elem in self.members if elem != integer]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def without_element(l, element):
    return [item for item in l if item != element]

def remove_all(l, element):
    try:
        while True:
            l.remove(element)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

The first function makes a new list without any copies of the element you don't want. The second removes all copies from the existing list. There's no "remove all copies" method; usually, if you want that, you're using the wrong data structure. Are you sure you should be using a list?

Answer (score 0):

```
def remove_element(self,integer):
    while integer in self.members:
          self.members.remove(integer)
```